# How can I run that app even when my Iphone is locked?

Tags: iphone, cordova

I am using the PhoneGap Library (JavaScript), jQuery and HTML5 for app development.

I am stuck in a situation where my app is not responding when my iPhone is locked.
My app works fine for Android devices when the phone is locked.

How can I run my app even when my iPhone is locked?

Comment: Well, all you can do is prevent the auto lock to happen when your phone is idle for a while.. You can set the idletimer to disable but if user send the app to the background and lock it then you can't have control over it..

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, unless you are taking advantage of the background apis (voip, location, etc), but if your app doesnt really take advantage of those then you can't.